# Throws MyException returns NULL

Tags: java, exception

I have the next problem.

```
public Validator {

    ....

    public boolean validate() throws MyException
    ....
        if (!model.hasSomeCondition()) {
            throw getException(model);
        }
    ....
    return true;
}

....

public MyException getException (MyModel aModel) {
    MyException exception = new MyException(aModel.getFirstName());
    return exception;
}

....

public static class MyException extends Exception {
 ...
}

....


}
```

When I catch exception, object is null all time!

What is wrong? I can't understand.

PS. Thanks for help.

Comment: *Which* object is null? The model? The model's first name? that would make sense since you throw the exception when it doesn't have one!

Comment: @Paranaix: no, that's incorrect. The new is located in the `getException(...)` method.

Comment: I tried to move logic from getException to validation method. Nothing was changed

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Explain your self. When instantiating a object one has to invoke the constructor with `new`. This is not a cpp related question.

Comment: @Paranaix: he is calling `getException(...)` in the throws statement. In that method he creates a *new MyException* object and returns it. That is the ***new*** that you are looking for. It's all in the code above.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels the `new` wasnt there at the time i wrote the comment

Comment: @Rusfearuth is the MyException returned what's NULL?

Answer (score 3):

Regarding this code:

```
public boolean validate() throws MyException
    ....
        if (!model.hasFirstName()) {
            throw getException(model);
        }
    ....
    return true;
}

....

public MyException getException (MyModel aModel) {
    MyException exception = new MyException(aModel.getFirstName());
    return exception;
}
```

It would make sense that `aModel.getFirstName()` returns null since the exception is thrown if aModel *has no* first name.

If this is not the problem you're having then please clarify your question. A ***lot***.

Comment: I've checked by debuger. It isn't null

Comment: @Rusfearuth Then why would `hasFirstName()` return `false`?

Comment: @Rusfearuth: then what exactly ***is*** null? Again, please clarify your problem greatly!

Comment: @Rusfearuth: No, you've obfuscated the issue. Please put a little effort into explaining what's going on. You're assuming that we can read code not seen or can read your mind, and we can't.

Comment: try { if (validator.validate()) { /* do something */ } } catch (Validator.MyException e) { /* do something */ }. "e" is null

Comment: @Rusfearuth: It appears to me that the code you've posted doesn't match the error you're having. Either the problem is occurring elsewhere or the code is off.